# Concurrency: large pandas DataFrame used to serve real-time queries

Tags: python, pandas, concurrency, multiprocessing

We have a large pandas DataFrame (several Gb) that is kept in memory. The application is a machine learning web service, and it is replying to real-time queries.

Each query can contain up to 20,000 integers, designating the rows of the DataFrame that the query relates to. (Different users have access to different items because of the geographic location.)  The service then selects those rows and does some fancy machine learning on them, in order to produce an answer for the user.

It is working fairly well, but now we want to scale it further. Currently it can only process one request at a time, asynchronously. We can just run several copies, but that would mean duplicating the data, and we may not have that much memory. What would be a good solution?

- write some module that would just hold the data, and send pickled DataFrames with 20,000 items to whoever needs them? If I am correct, there were some remote-procedure-call solutions in python using, I think, pyzmq.
- use a blaze server to do the same thing (if it is possible).
- try to put the dataframe into a shared memory space in some way. I am not quite sure how to do it properly, and I've already managed to get weird bugs whereas a DataFrame, if not properly locked, would get into an inconsistent state from read-only operations (presumably because of some internal data structures necessary to create the views?)
- use a nonstandard python interpreter without a GIL, but one that does allow you to use pandas (do they even exist?), and then again, figure out how to protect the access...

Answer (score 3):

Are you using the DataFrame itself in the ML code, or are you creating NumPy arrays from the DataFrame which are then passed to the ML code?

If the latter, and assuming that the NumPy arrays are created quickly compared to the time required to run the ML code, I'd think the solution would be to have a single process to read the DataFrame and create the NumPy arrays, then make the arrays available to separate processes running the ML code via shared memory (see for instance the SharedArray package https://pypi.python.org/pypi/SharedArray), then use multiprocessing.Queue or multiprocessing.Pipe to synchronize the DF and ML processes.

Comment: I am extracting a sub-dataframe by using `.loc` with a list of indexes I am interested in. Then I am using some columns in it to get some more data from smaller dataframes (that can be duplicated). I also have some precomputed data that looks like a dictionary with numpy arrays as values.    Thank you for the suggestion! Do you know why it can share numpy arrays but not DataFrames? That is, is there some internal mechanics in the DataFrames that is problematic?

Comment: SharedArray is implemented using Numpy's C api, its specific to Numpy array's